# Code Complexity Analysis for c++ on unix which can generate xml output

Tags: c++, c, xml, unix, complexity-theory

I am looking for a code complxity analysis tool for c++ which can run on unix and generate output in the form of an xml file. 
something like this : http://www.blunck.info/ccm.html
This tool works on windows but i need something which runs on unix.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could try pmccabe (http://parisc-linux.org/~bame/pmccabe/). It operates on the code before preprocessing - so may not work well always.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually run the ccm binaries on Unix as well. You just have to install [mono](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html), and then invoke ccm like this:

```
mono ./CCM.exe <config details>
```

You would have to manually copy over CCM.exe and CCMEngine.dll from Windows though, as there is no separate package for that.

[1](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) http://www.blunck.se/ccm.html